# update RHS on a constraint in scip using python

Tags: python-3.5, scip

Are there any good solutions for updating the rhs of a constraint? Preferably I would like to do something like:

```
    import pyscipopt as scp
    Mod=scp.Model()
    x=Mod.addVar(ub=3,name="x")
    y=Mod.addVar(ub=4,name="y")
    c=Mod.addCons(x+y<=2,"C1")
    Mod.setObjective(0.5*x+0.3*y, "maximize")
    Mod.optimize()
    print(Mod.getObjVal())
    c.updateRHS(4) # This function does not exist..
    Mod.optimize()
    print(Mod.getObjVal())
```

Comment: I just created a new issue for this in the corresponding GitHub project: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/issues/64

Comment: I guess for such a scenario, you would do even more, e.g., keep the best solution from the previous iteration (since you relax your constraint)

Comment: Thanks Matt! I could mark an answer from you as accepted, given your pull request that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of PySCIPOpt (see https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/pull/70)

The methods are called `chgLhs()` and `chgRhs()`. Keep in mind that they are only going to work for linear and quadratic constraints for now.